# Automatic creation of Duplicate files in git

Tags: git, github, version-control, gitlab

its very strange behaviour I have noticed while using git 
only in my GitHub projects ,
my project start creating duplicate files on its own. 
I am really fed up of that now .

what I have tried to resolve it ?
ans : 1. cleared git cache .
2. removed git and added git again
3. manually deleted all duplicate files (again they appear after some time)

not able to pick up a situation when this happens! 
[image]

Comment: Are you using iCloud or a similar syncing service?  Does this happen if you just use the command line and not any other tool or IDE?

Comment: yes they are being backed up on my iCloud ! and yes I am using terminal for git commands

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're seeing this problem because you're using a cloud-based syncing service, which in this case is iCloud.  Such services can recreate files like this in an unwanted way.

In addition, cloud-based file syncing services sync file by file, which works great for things like word-processing documents, but can corrupt repositories if the sync happens when the repository isn't idle, since they can sync some parts of the repository without syncing others.

In order to solve this problem, exclude all of your repositories from iCloud syncing.  If you need to transfer things via iCloud, use a tarball of your repository instead, since that's a single file.  You can also use `rsync`, but only when the repository is completely idle.

Comment: are u sure about this ? I will check it by moving my project into non-icloud folder!

Comment: People see this behavior using other cloud-syncing services, so I expect it's the cause of the problem.  Git certainly isn't doing it itself, so if it's not iCloud, it's something else on your system you haven't told us about.